# json.net support for json schema version 4 validation against json data

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I would like to know, JSON.Net has support for json data validation against json schema version 4.  Currently I don't see any information on the same, where currently it has support for version 3.  And can let me know any plans to implement this in JSON.Net schema validation in near future.

Thanks, I appreciate your valuable input on the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>No. It has not support for Draft 4 and [no plans to support it so far](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/24700).</s>

**Update:**

**[Json.NET Schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema)** has full support for Draft 4.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a look at [NJsonSchema](http://njsonschema.org) for an alternative to Json.NET. The library also supports the generation of C# and TypeScript code from a JSON schema.